# ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=4000] error

Tags: texmf, bakoma

What is save_size bounded by? I used Bakoma tex and I can only change the save_size in TEXMF.INI to a maximum of 7000 and if I go above it the program will crash.
[image]

```
%
\documentclass[10pt,letter,notitlepage]{article}
%Mise en page
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, lines=45, top=0.8in, bottom=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand\Loadedframemethod{TikZ}
\usepackage[framemethod=\Loadedframemethod]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}



\newcommand{\RR}{\mathds{R}}
\newcommand{\sign}{\mathop{\mathrm{sign}}}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\mathop{\mathrm{argmin}}}
\newcommand{\zero}{\mathbf{0}}
\newcommand{\one}{\mathbf{1}}
\newcommand{\bv}{\mathbf{b}}
\newcommand{\wv}{\mathbf{w}}
\newcommand{\xv}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\yv}{\mathbf{y}}
\newcommand{\rv}{\mathbf{r}}
\newcommand{\inner}[2]{\langle #1, #2 \rangle}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}
\newcommand{\magenta}[1]{{\color{magenta}#1}}


\newcommand{\ea}{{et al.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\eg}{{e.g.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ie}{{i.e.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\iid}{{i.i.d.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\cf}{{cf.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\wrt}{{w.r.t.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\aka}{{a.k.a.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\etc}{{etc.}\xspace}

\newcommand{\ans}[1]{{\color{orange}\textsf{Ans}: #1}}



%================================
%================================

\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\tikzstyle{titregris} =
[draw=gray,fill=white, shading = exersicetitle, %
text=gray, rectangle, rounded corners, right,minimum height=.3cm]
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{exersicebackground}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(green!40); color(100bp)=(black!5)}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{exersicetitle}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(red!40);color(100bp)=(black!5)}
\newcounter{exercise}
\renewcommand*\theexercise{exercice \textbf{Exercice}~n\arabic{exercise}}
\makeatletter
\def\mdf@@exercisepoints{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{exercisepoints}{%
\def\mdf@@exercisepoints{#1}
}

\mdfdefinestyle{exercisestyle}{%
outerlinewidth=1em,outerlinecolor=white,%
leftmargin=-1em,rightmargin=-1em,%
middlelinewidth=0.5pt,roundcorner=3pt,linecolor=black,
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style ={%
shading = exersicebackground}}},
innertopmargin=0.1\baselineskip,
skipabove={\dimexpr0.1\baselineskip+0\topskip\relax},
skipbelow={-0.1em},
needspace=0.5\baselineskip,
frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
settings={\global\stepcounter{exercise}},
singleextra={%
\node[titregris,xshift=0.5cm] at (P-|O) %
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\theexercise}~};
\ifdefempty{\mdf@@exercisepoints}%
{}%
{\node[titregris,left,xshift=-1cm] at (P)%
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@@exercisepoints points}~};}%
},
firstextra={%
\node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\theexercise}~};
\ifdefempty{\mdf@@exercisepoints}%
{}%
{\node[titregris,left,xshift=-1cm] at (P)%
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@@exercisepoints points}~};}%
},
}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
outerlinewidth=0.01em,linecolor=black,middlelinewidth=0.5pt,%
frametitlerule=true,roundcorner=2pt,%
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mfframetitlebackground/.append style={%
shade,left color=white, right color=blue!20}}},
frametitlerulecolor=black,innertopmargin=1\baselineskip,%green!60,
innerbottommargin=0.5\baselineskip,
frametitlerulewidth=0.1pt,
innertopmargin=0.7\topskip,skipabove={\dimexpr0.2\baselineskip+0.1\topskip\relax},
frametitleaboveskip=1pt,
frametitlebelowskip=1pt
}
\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{10mm}
\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{exercise}{\textbf{Exercise}}

%================Liste definition--numList-and alphList=============
\newcounter{alphListCounter}
\newenvironment
{alphList}
{\begin{list}
{\alph{alphListCounter})}
{\usecounter{alphListCounter}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0.2cm}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\parsep}{0cm}}
}
{\end{list}}
\newcounter{numListCounter}
\newenvironment
{numList}
{\begin{list}
{\arabic{numListCounter})}
{\usecounter{numListCounter}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\parsep}{0cm}}
}
{\end{list}}

\usepackage[letterpaper=true,linkcolor=magenta,urlcolor=magenta,citecolor=black]{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}


%===========================================================
\begin{document}





\begin{exercise}[Perceptron Implementation (5 pts)]
\blue{\textbf{Convention:} All algebraic operations, when applied to a vector
or matrix, are understood to be element-wise (unless otherwise stated).}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
        \KwIn{$X\in\RR^{n\times d}$, $\yv\in \{-1,1\}^n$, $\wv=\zero_d$,
$b=0$, $\mathsf{max\_pass} \in \mathds{N}$}

        \KwOut{$\wv, b, mistake$}

        \For{$t=1, 2, \ldots, \mathsf{max\_pass}$ }{
                $mistake(t) \gets 0$

                \For{$i=1, 2, \ldots, n$}{
                        \If{$y_i (\inner{\xv_i}{\wv}+b) \leq 0$}{
                                $\wv \gets \wv + y_i\xv_i$ \tcp*{$\xv_i$
is the $i$-th row of $X$}

                                $b \gets b + y_i$

                                $mistake(t) \gets mistake(t) + 1$
                        }       
                }
        }
        \caption{The perceptron algorithm.}
        \label{alg:perceptron}
\end{algorithm}

Implement the perceptron in \Cref{alg:perceptron}. Your implementation should
take input as $X = [\xv_1^\top, \ldots, \xv_n^\top]^\top \in \RR^{n \times
d}$, $\yv \in \{-1,1\}^{n}$, an initialization of the hyperplane parameters
$\wv\in\RR^{d}$ and $b\in \RR$, and the maximum number of passes of the training
set [suggested $\mathsf{max\_pass} = 500$]. Run your perceptron algorithm
on the \href{https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/spambase}{\magenta{\textsf{spambase}}}
dataset (available on \href{https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~y328yu/mycourses/480/assignment.html}{\magenta{course
website}}), and plot the number of mistakes ($y$-axis) \wrt the number of
passes ($x$-axis).

\ans{   }

\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[Linear Regression (5 pts)]
Recall that ridge regression refers to the following $\ell_2$ norm regularized
linear regression problem:
\begin{align}
\label{eq:rr}
\min_{\wv} ~ \tfrac12\|X\wv - \yv\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\wv\|_2^2,
\end{align}
where $X \in \RR^{n\times d}, \yv \in \RR^n$ and $\wv \in \RR^d$. Obviously,
setting $\lambda = 0$ we recover ordinary linear regression. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item (3 pts) Prove that ridge regression with any $\lambda > 0$ is equivalent
to ordinary linear regression after performing the following data augmentation:
\begin{align}
\label{eq:da1}
X &\gets \begin{bmatrix} X \\ \sqrt{2\lambda} I_{d \times d} \end{bmatrix}
\\
\label{eq:da2}
\yv &\gets \begin{bmatrix} \yv \\ 0_{d} \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
where $I_{d\times d}$ is the $d\times d$ identity matrix and $0_d$ is the
$d$-dimensional zero vector.

\ans{}

\item (2 pts) Explain the data augmentation step \eqref{eq:da1}-\eqref{eq:da2}.
[E.g., what kind of data are we adding to the training set? how many of them?
their dimension? what effect are they bringing to the weight vector $\wv$?]

\ans{}
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}


\end{document}
```

Comment: the save stack is where tex saves values that need to be restored at the end of a group. If you use that much it usually indicates an error in your code, eg making local and global alignments to the same register which can use unlimited amounts of stack.

Comment: the default save stack in texlive 2020 is 80000

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you help me check the error? I have my console as below.

Comment: you would need to add a small but complete document with save stack use over 4000 to your question so we can debug it. You could also try running your document on overleaf which is texlive so as a bigger save stack.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can compile on the overleaf whereas it gives me the error on my local so I think the problem will be the setup

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My full document has added

Comment: your document uses 1149 stack positions (out of 80000 on texlive) but should be well under the limit you show of 4000

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, do you mean that there is a problem with the software?